# How to define direction of reference in iFrameAI

Tags: database

I'm working with iFrameAI and have come across a scenario where I need to define the direction of a reference. I understand that iFrameAI uses graph databases where nodes can be connected by edges in a specific direction. However, I'm not sure how to specify this direction when defining references in iFrameAI. Could someone please guide me on how to establish the direction of a reference in iFrameAI?

I tried to use the `in_` and `out` methods on the vertex (`traversal.V(id)`) for "in" and "out" directions, respectively. I was expecting these methods to control the direction of the edges, but lack of specific direction definition is causing the "out" edges to overwrite the "in" edges in my current setup.